# Submesh not appearing with different materials Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I have some code that creates a circular mesh, it takes a radius, a number of sides (which is selected to be around 100 for a circle) and an Outline Width. It initialises the mesh as follows:

```
MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
mf.mesh = mesh;

mesh.subMeshCount = 2;
```

It assigns the vertices with a bit of maths that isn't entirely self explanatory but I guess trust that it assigns vertices as a regular polygon with n sides, and then again for an outline:

```
//vertices
List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3> { };
float x;
float y;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x = radius * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    y = radius * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    y = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
}
Vector3[] vertices = verticesList.ToArray();
```

There are then two triangles list and `mesh.SetTriangles()` is used later to make two submeshes with these two triangle arrays:

```
//triangles
List<int> trianglesList = new List<int> { };
List<int> OLtrianglesList = new List<int> { };
for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
{
    trianglesList.Add(0);
    trianglesList.Add(i + 1);
    trianglesList.Add(i + 2);
}
for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
{
    trianglesList.Add(n);
    trianglesList.Add(i + n + 1);
    trianglesList.Add(i + n + 2);
}
int[] triangles = trianglesList.ToArray();
int[] OLtriangles = OLtrianglesList.ToArray();
```

All the normals are simply `-Vector3.forward`:

```
//normals
List<Vector3> normalsList = new List<Vector3> { };
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
{
    normalsList.Add(-Vector3.forward);
}
Vector3[] normals = normalsList.ToArray();
```

Then I initialise the mesh as follows:

```
//initialise
mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.normals = normals;
mesh.SetTriangles(triangles, 0);
mesh.SetTriangles(OLtriangles, 1);
```

So the full code looks like this (there is a polycollider set up at the end but that's irrelevant for this):

```
public void PolyMesh(float radius, int n, float OLwidth)
{
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh = mesh;

    mesh.subMeshCount = 2;

    //vertices
    List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3> { };
    float x;
    float y;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = radius * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
        y = radius * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
        verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
        y = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
        verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
    }
    Vector3[] vertices = verticesList.ToArray();

    //triangles
    List<int> trianglesList = new List<int> { };
    List<int> OLtrianglesList = new List<int> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
    {
        trianglesList.Add(0);
        trianglesList.Add(i + 1);
        trianglesList.Add(i + 2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
    {
        trianglesList.Add(n);
        trianglesList.Add(i + n + 1);
        trianglesList.Add(i + n + 2);
    }
    int[] triangles = trianglesList.ToArray();
    int[] OLtriangles = OLtrianglesList.ToArray();

    //normals
    List<Vector3> normalsList = new List<Vector3> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        normalsList.Add(-Vector3.forward);
    }
    Vector3[] normals = normalsList.ToArray();

    //initialise
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.normals = normals;
    mesh.SetTriangles(triangles, 0);
    mesh.SetTriangles(OLtriangles, 1);

    //polyCollider
    polyCollider.pathCount = 1;

    List<Vector2> pathList = new List<Vector2> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pathList.Add(new Vector2(vertices[i + n].x, vertices[i + n].y));
    }
    Vector2[] path = pathList.ToArray();

    polyCollider.SetPath(0, path);
}
```

So as far as I'm aware this should have set up two meshes, one slightly bigger than the other. This works, however they always appear as the same colour despite assigning two different materials to the Mesh Renderer.

This is how the mesh appears in the game:

[image]

And this shows there are clearly two meshes:

[image]

My Mesh Renderer is as follows:

[image]

And these are the materials in use:

[image]

I have tried simply swapping the materials round in the renderer but that just makes the object a single material with the other material.

After further experimentation I want to clarify this isn’t caused by Z-fighting, I’ve experimented by changing the z coordinate of the outline and changed the materials in real time and they both have the same material no matter what I do for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

## Your 'outline' mesh is not correctly constructed.

Your "outline" mesh is, in fact, a circle, not a ring.

Because of this, when the entire thing is rendered, the outline and the inner portion are in the same place. If you were to move the camera around I suspect you'd see some [Z-Fighting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AcCrF_nX-I).

To correctly render your object, you need to actually create a *ring* for your outline.

Secondly, you're smashing both "submeshes" together into a single triangles array:

```
List<int> trianglesList = new List<int> { };
List<int> OLtrianglesList = new List<int> { };
for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
{
    trianglesList.Add(0);
    trianglesList.Add(i + 1);
    trianglesList.Add(i + 2);
}
for (int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++)
{
    trianglesList.Add(n);
    trianglesList.Add(i + n + 1);
    trianglesList.Add(i + n + 2);
}
```

Notice that `OLtrianglesList` is not used!

It probably doesn't help that you use a single list for both sets of verticies, either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x = radius * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    y = radius * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Sin((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    y = (radius + OLwidth) * Mathf.Cos((2 * Mathf.PI * i) / n);
    verticesList.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
}
```

Comment: Can I not have it so that the outline circle is rendered ‘behind’ the other one? Without having to render a ring? I have a box and ramp object with the same method and they seem to cope with a larger mesh of the same shape being behind the other just fine

Comment: You could, but you'd have to make sure that the Z value of the verticies of the outline is different from that of the inner part. And it'll only look like an outline from one side.

Comment: So after a bit more testing I’ve established the problem is nothing to do with Z-fighting, each mesh simply has the same material no matter what I try

Comment: Ah I see, as far as I’ve seen with regard to vertices being of the same list that it should be okay but yes OLtrianglesList is not in use, thank you for spotting it